# Local shape color blending

Tags: opengl, directx, glsl, shader, hlsl

I am trying to implement [this](http://seblagarde.wordpress.com/2012/09/29/image-based-lighting-approaches-and-parallax-corrected-cubemap/) in Unity 4 Pro.

But I am stuck in the blending part. I don't understand how you could blend multiples textures/colors using multiples volumes on an object. How could you access those volumes in the shader and check for "collision"?

It's seems to be very similar to vertex/pixel lighting. But maybe I am wrong.

Here is the simple effect I am trying to create.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this method is about a method to interpolate between different environment maps (given as cube maps). The image posted looks like a visualization of the interpolation strategy. That is, as a point moves through the world, various environment maps are used with different weighting (eg 10% of one, 70% of another and 20% of a third) to give a smooth transition. Not really a point but rather a surface realized in fragments which use a number of environment maps to approximate an environment map for that fragments location.

To answer your question, "checking for collision" should probably be done CPU side, and a list of volumes (really 3D shapes) passed in. For example, if you draw something that could intersect the environment map's area of contribution add the map to a list and pass all of them to the shader drawing the object. Using a physics trigger in unity is probably the easiest way to get started with this.

Once you have a list of weights, sample each environment map (by direction and maybe mip level), scale the sample by the weight and sum for the result.